# Docker cannot create a machine - Error in driver during machine creation

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-toolbox

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjr2U.png)

when the first time i run the Docker Quickstart Terminal , i got below message,the machine cannot be create.

> Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
>   Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...

does anyone have some idea?

Versions of related components:
DockerToolbox-1.9.0
Windows 7 sp1
VirtualBox Version 5.0.8 r103449

Answer (score 1):

Without using docker quickstart, make sure [`docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.5/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe) (the latest 0.5.5 version) is in your path and type:

```
cd /path/to/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe

docker-machine ls
docker-machine create -d virtualbox anewmachine
docker-machine ssh anewmachine
```

(if dokcer-machine is already in your PATH because of the docker Toolbox installation, you have nothing to download: just type `docker-machine version` to check its version)

Comment: I was creating my node without passing the `-d virtualbox`. After I've added that it works perfectly!